# Django HStoreField different output from shell

Tags: python, django

here is my sample model

```
class PaymentPlan(TimeStampedModel):
    payment_list = HStoreField(
        _('payment dates'),
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

shell_plus

```
In [3]: i=EnrollmentInfo.objects.get(pk=580441)
In [4]: i.payment_plan.payment_list
Out[4]: '"Invoice-1"=>"2019-07-31"'  <--- str

In [5]: e=EnrollmentInfo.objects.get(pk=580441)
In [6]: e.payment_plan.payment_list
Out[6]: {u'Invoice-1': u'2019-07-31'} <---dict
```

im having an error on my code because i was expecting the hstorefield to be a dictionary.

anyone knows why hstorefield has different output? thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution now

on your shell

```
from django.db import connection
from psycopg2.extras import register_hstore
register_hstore(connection.connection)
```

this will return dictionary now